# AngularJS replaced directive on specific pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an index.html with the main view and 2 directive, on for the site header and one for the footer:

```
 <div class="site">

<!-- header -->
<header pb-ds-header pb-fixed-navbar></header>

<!-- content -->
<div ui-view="" class="view-animate site-content" autoscroll="false"></div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer pb-ds-footer></footer>

</div>
```

The header directive is

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('pbDsHeader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'modules/main/templates/header.html',
    controller: 'HeaderController as header'
  };
});

})();
```

OK, works fine.  There are a few pages where there is no header required, here I use a `body` class to hide the header.

However, now I have several pages where I need to display a *different header template* than the rest of the site has.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I would use a child view for the header, and then have two views for the two different headers.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'd use UI-Router's [Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views):

```
<div class="site">

<!-- header -->
<div ui-view="header"></div>

<!-- content -->
<div ui-view="body" class="view-animate site-content" autoscroll="false"></div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer pb-ds-footer></footer>

</div>
```

and in your routes definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('some.state', {
    views: {
      header: 'modules/main/templates/header.html',
      body: 'templates/some/body.html'
    }
  })
  .state('some.other.state', {
    views: {
      header: '', // no header in this state
      body: 'templates/other/body.html'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I did, was to setup multiple directive templates, and hide them with `ng-show=someVar`, and using routing logic, apply false or true to the scope variables to show or hide specific directives.

Here's an example:

```
$scope.modelPaths = {
    impactModel : true,
    sourceFields : false,
    filterModel : false,
    fieldCards : false
};

//apply pathing logic here
$scope.path = function(url) {
    angular.forEach($scope.modelPaths, function(value, model) {
        console.log(model);
        $scope.modelPaths[model] = false;
    });
    $scope.modelPaths[url] = true;
}
```

And on the html side, I used this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 bordered" id="modalData">
    <filter-model ng-show="modelPaths.filterModel"></filter-model>
    <field-cards ng-show="modelPaths.cardModel"></field-cards>
</div>
```